# Couchdb purge whole database

Tags: couchdb

I'm quite sure that I want to delete a database in order to release my resources. I'll never need replication nor the old version, nor logs anymore. But despite my frequently deletion of the database and recreating another, the disk space increases gradually.

**How can I simply get rid of the whole database and it's affects on the disk?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deleting the database via `DELETE /db-name` removes the database's data and associated indexes on disk. The database is as deleted as it's going to be.

If you are using [the purge feature](http://couchdb.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/api/database/misc.html#db-purge) to remove all the documents in the database, instead consider a `DELETE` followed by a `PUT` to recreate.

Logs are a different matter, as they are not database-specific, but for the database engine itself. It might be that you need to clear old logs, but you will probably only be able to do that on a time-based rather than database-based manner.